Predicting continuous variable based on curve
I have a dataset of a set of curves measured at different frequencies, so it is composed of curves as the figure below for example. My dataset has many more curves of course. A curve is associated with a continuous dependent variable such as height. Which machine learning method would allow me to predict the value of the dependent variable based on the curve as a whole?
I have thought of linear mixed effects, but is there a machine learning method such as Gaussian processes, and does anyone know of an example of how I can do this?
I don't have experience with Gaussian processes but I want to learn how to do it.


If you have the curve, what are you trying to predict that you don't already know?

i'm trying to predict the height based on the entire curve, here the frequencies are not independent.

Is there structure in the data that indicates a need for a hierarchical/mixed model? If not and it's just a few curves like this, I would use something simpler like splines.

This sounds like a perfect time for [tag:functional-data-analysis].
